# Convert dataframe column to dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
title|year
test1|2001
test2|2002
test3|2004
```

I want the year column to be converted into dd/mm/yyyy format.
The expected output is as follows:

```
title|year
test1|1/1/2001
test2|1/1/2002
test3|1/1/2004
```

Is there anyway to achieve that output?

Comment: Do you mean to cap your year with 1/1 to your year?

Comment: Use `df['year']= pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y')`

Comment: If need add `1/1/` then use  `df['year'] = '1/1/' + df['year'].astype(str)`

Comment: @jezrael the second one works perfect